# check of myFinal == null don't work in flutter

Tags: database, flutter, dart, http, null

my Final declaration check if it's null don't work in flutter
`if (extractedData == null) { return; }`

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetOrders() async {
    const url = 'https://flutter-update.firebaseio.com/orders.json';
    final response = await http.get(url);
    final List<OrderItem> loadedOrders = [];
    final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    if (extractedData == null) {
      return;
    }
  }
```

i try to look if if

extractedData == null

but flutter say that *The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true. *

Comment: Why are you checking `extractedData == null`? In other words, what leads you think the result of `json.decode()` could be `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are giving extractedData variable data of type Map<String, dynamic> which will not be null-able and will throw error if json.decode() return a null value so if you wan to make it null-able change the

```
final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

to this

```
final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>?;
```

so the type of extractedData will be Map<String,dynamic>? which can also store null value and then you can use condition on it .

Comment: There is only one situation where `json.decode()` will return `null`, and that's `json.decode('null')`. I don't think it makes sense to make this nullable *unless* one is explicitly expecting `response.body` to possibly be the text `'null'`.

Comment: sometimes the response.body is returned as null there are a lot factor causing this and if you are sure that null will not be returned so there is no need for using this condition if (extractedData == null)

Comment: la solution a bien marché pour moi. merci @Munsif Ali

Comment: can you explain it in English please

Answer (score 0):

You need to make extractedData nullable:

```
// Add the ? at the end
final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>?;
```

Comment: There is only one situation where `json.decode()` will return `null`, and that's `json.decode('null')`. I don't think it makes sense to make this nullable *unless* one is explicitly expecting `response.body` to possibly be the text `'null'`.